# how can I install package from a downloaded zip

Tags: installation, emacs

I am behind a firewall on MS Windows and setting the proxy in my init file did not work. I can download the zip archive from GitHub, but when the package has many `.el` files the `install-from-file` does not work. I tried saving the folder as `.tar` but it still did not work.

How can I install the downloaded folder? There is a `Makefile` in the folder, but I have no `make` or its alternatives on Windows and will not be allowed to install them.

Prior to the migration to GitHub I was able to download a single file from Melpa and that worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

a workaround is to add the package folder to your `load-path` and then `require` the package.

This will not take care of any dependencies, so watch in `*Warnings*` and `*Messages*` buffers for any problems caused by unmet dependencies.

See the details [here](https://polymode.github.io/installation/).